# Multilingual JPA entity mapping

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.1

Using this example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY (
    COUNTRY_CODE            VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    DIALLING_CODE           VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CREATED_BY              VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY         VARCHAR(20),
    DELETION_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP NULL,
    DELETED_BY              VARCHAR(20),

    PRIMARY KEY(NUMERIC_CODE),
    UNIQUE(ALPHA2_CODE),
    UNIQUE(ALPHA3_CODE),
    UNIQUE(DIALLING_CODE),
    FOREIGN KEY(CREATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY(LAST_UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (DELETED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY_NAME (
    COUNTRY_CODE            VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    LANGUAGE_CODE           VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    NAME                    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CREATED_BY              VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY         VARCHAR(20),

    PRIMARY KEY (COUNTRY_CODE, LANGUAGE_CODE),
    FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRY_CODE) REFERENCES COUNTRY (COUNTRY_CODE),
    FOREIGN KEY (LANGUAGE_CODE) REFERENCES LANGUAGE (ALPHA2_CODE),
    FOREIGN KEY (CREATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (LAST_UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The JPA representation for Country is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Cacheable
public class Country extends AbstractSoftDeleteAuditableEntity<String> implements za.co.sindi.persistence.entity.Entity<String>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4019436514961967327L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COUNTRY_CODE", length=3, nullable=false)
    @Size(min=3, max=3)
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\d{3}$")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="DIALLING_CODE", length=5, nullable=false)
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\+[0-9]{2,5}$")
    private String diallingCode;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="country")
    private List<CountryName> names;


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see za.co.sindi.entity.IDBasedEntity#getId()
     */
    public String getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see za.co.sindi.entity.IDBasedEntity#setId(java.io.Serializable)
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the diallingCode
     */
    public String getDiallingCode() {
        return diallingCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param diallingCode the diallingCode to set
     */
    public void setDiallingCode(String diallingCode) {
        this.diallingCode = diallingCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the names
     */
    public List<CountryName> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    /**
     * @param names the names to set
     */
    public void setNames(List<CountryName> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }
}
```

With the above model, I will have to iterate `names` attribute to find a `CountryName` which matches a language code.

Is there a better way to retrieve a `Country` and `CountryName` based on a language code? If not, how can I achieve a simpler approach that can allow me to pull a `Country` information with language code to an entity like as follows:

```
public class Country implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4019436514961967327L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="COUNTRY_CODE", length=3, nullable=false)
        @Size(min=3, max=3)
        @Pattern(regexp="^\\d{3}$")
        private String id;

        @Column(name="DIALLING_CODE", length=5, nullable=false)
        @Pattern(regexp="^\\+[0-9]{2,5}$")
        private String diallingCode;

        private String name;

        private Language language;


        //Getters and setters will be auto generated here....
}
```

That way, this can be achieved:

```
Country country = countryDAO.find(countryCode);
System.out.println(country.getName());
```

Comment: Why don't you use a separate query just for `CountryName`?

Comment: I thought about it & that would mean I have to create a `CountryNameDAO` then since I'm using DAO pattern throughout.

Comment: If that is not what you would want to do (though it might be a best option), you might add a `@Transient java.util.Map` field to `Country` entity which you would fill with `CountryName`s. You could then access it by `country.getName(countryCode)`. The performance gain might not be great though, unless you cache country data.

Comment: `Map` option might not be best as you want it to lazy load. I am looking for best approach so if a `CountryNameDAO` is the best option, I'll go for it.

Comment: Lazy wouldn't be a problem, as you would populate the map on first access to `country.getName(countryCode)`.

Comment: How do I achieve using `Map` in JPA then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I think the best solution would be to use a separate query (and DAO) for `CountryName`, because it would avoid loading unnecessary country names when you only need one for specified `countryCode`.

One option is to use a `@Transient java.util.Map` field which would be loaded with country names, with `countryCode` as map key,

```
@Transient
private Map<String, CountryName> countryNameMap;
...
public CountryName getName(String countryCode) {
    if (countryNameMap == null) {
        countryNameMap = loadNamesIntoMap(); // a loop with countryNameMap.put(countryName.getCountryCode(), countryName)
    }
    return countryNameMap.get(countryCode);
}
```

Another interesting option is to actually use `java.util.Map` for relation between `Country` and `CountryName`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
@MapKey(name="countryCode")
private Map<String, CountryName> names;
```

You would then access the name with `country.getNames().get(countryCode)`.

Comment: I used a separate DAO as there were different queries that needed to be added on `CountryName` so your first statement is the actual solution. Thanks.